# Is this subset of group, a subgroup of it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group, $n = |G|$, and $X$ be a non-empty subset of $G$. Is it true that 
$$
H := \{ x_1 x_2 \dots x_n | x_i \in X \}
$$
is a subgroub of $G$?

Edit:
Since $n=|G|$ so $H$ has identity. But whether $H$ is closed under group's operation? Since $G$ is finite it solves the problem.

Comment: Why do you say "$n = |G|$ so $H$ has identity"?

Comment: $X$ is not empty so it has an element, $x$, now $1=x^n \in X$

Comment: Sorry about all wrong directions. Im very confused now. How did you prove that the inverse element is in H? That kills the problem.

Comment: Sorry! But I did not prove that!

Comment: This question was asked before, I gave an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475657/a-special-subgroup-of-groups-of-order-n/476589#476589). Where did you find this problem by the way? I am interested because I've only seen it here on Math.SE.

Comment: My friend asks me. I'm not sure from his resource for the problem. Thank for link!