# Prove that $\langle S \rangle$ $\leq$ G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $S \subset G$ where $S \neq \emptyset$. Prove that $\langle S \rangle$ $\leq$ G. In this problem $\langle S \rangle$ is the set generated by S.

Now, I know that if $s \in\langle S \rangle$, then $s=s_1*s_2*s_3 ...*s_n$ where each of the $s_i \in S$. Then because $S \subset G$, and $G$ is a group we have that $s \in G$.

I'm supposed to use the 1-step subgroup test. Showing that if $a,b \in\langle S \rangle$, then $ab^{-1}$ $\in\langle S \rangle$. But i'm stuck.

Comment: Do you mean that $\langle S\rangle$ is the *subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$*?

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: Your definition of $S$ doesn't seem to be the right one to me, except if you are asking for something like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475657). What is precisely your definition of $\langle S \rangle$ ?

Comment: I want to show that the set generated by <S> is a subgroup of G.

Comment: In this case, $\langle S\rangle$ should be defined as the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $S$; intersections of subgroups are again subgroups (easy exercise) and so $\langle S\rangle$ is (trivially) a subgroup.

Comment: It looks as though you are unsure of the definition of $\langle S \rangle$. You cannot hope to solve a problem if you do not know the definitions of the terms involved.

Answer (score 1):

If $a = s_1 s_2 \cdots s_n$ and $b = s_{n+1} s_{n+2} \cdots s_{n+m}$ then $ab^{-1} = s_1 s_2 \cdots s_n s_{n+m}^{-1} \cdots s_{n+2}^{-1} s_{n+1}^{-1}$, which is a product of elements of $S$.

Comment: How do we know that the inverses are in <S>?

Comment: These should be included in the definition of $\langle S \rangle$. Otherwise the result is false, as can be seen by taking $S = \{1\}$ as subset of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$.