# Examples of application of theories to completely unexpected structures?

Tags: big-list, axioms

AFAIK, every mathematical theory (by which I mean e.g. the theory of groups, topologies, or vector spaces), started out (historically speaking) by formulating a set of axioms that generalize a specific structure, or a specific set of structures.

For example, when people think of a “field” they AFAIK usually think of $\mathbb R$, or $\mathbb C$. A topology started out as a concept defined on $\mathbb R^n$ if I’m not mistaken.

But I’ve also seen cases where a certain structure has a natural  topological structure, such as certain sets of propositions in first order logic. As far as I know, the people who formulated the axioms of a topology had no idea of this application. **And the topological structure of a set of FOL statements is certainly conceptually vastly different from one on $\mathbb R^n$, certainly not two structures I would have expected to have such a deep commonality.**

**I would like to make a list of examples of mathematical structures that**

1. Are interesting and well-behaved structures (e.g. not mere pathological counter examples)
2. satisfy the axioms of some mathematical theory in an interesting and nontrivial way,
3. But whose emergence is (conceptually/historically) very different from the structure of which those axioms were originally intended as a generalization.

Comment: Related: [Nice examples of groups which are not obviously groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362446)

Answer (score 2):

The useful [Zariski topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology) in algebraic geometry satisfies the usual axioms for a topology in  a context that doesn't really match "the structure of which those axioms were originally intended as a generalization".

Comment: This is the type of answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Several significant examples from mathematical physics:

- The usefulness of Hilbert space in the formalization of quantum
  mechanics.
- Riemannian manifolds as the appropriate language for general
  relativity.
- [Calabi -Yau manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold) come up in string theory.

Calculus for Newtonian mechanics doesn't count because the wish to formalize mechanics was much of what led Newton to invent calculus.

Answer (score 0):

The Peano's arithmetic was thought to axiomatize the structure of natural numbers. However, exists the structure of [non standar naturals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic) where exists a biggest natural number and satisfies that axioms.

Comment: That was not really what I was thinking of. Please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Number theory (the "structure of the integers") had no applications for years - a fact that particularly pleased G. H. Hardy.

Now it's central to cryptography: prime factorization, discrete logarithms, elliptic curves.

See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59537/how-come-public-key-cryptography-wasnt-discovered-earlier

(Not sure this counts.)